# Docker based php application profiling using blackfire

Tags: php, docker, blackfire

I am using a simple Docker-based PHP application ( https://github.com/fuhrysteve/php-docker-apache-example.git ) to demonstBlackfirekfire profiling:

**1. Install Chrome Extension for BlackFire ( on chrome )**

**2. define these environment variables:**

```
$export BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID=921b5dfa-a9e0-4979-8bd1-a7a7a2acf031
$export BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN=af050bfc9cf3761082828e3f5e4f31ada89649f0635c0cb445c86f26f72a8e18
$export BLACKFIRE_SERVER_ID=3534d1d9-7c0b-4c5b-9aad-eda497b27494
$export BLACKFIRE_SERVER_TOKEN=79082e6b82122630d6be03bb8f3f8c9544fadada78156ef4606d86f639644eb0
```

**3. Install Agent**

```
docker run --name="blackfire" -d -e BLACKFIRE_SERVER_ID -e BLACKFIRE_SERVER_TOKEN blackfire/blackfire
```

**4. Enabling the PHP Probe**
   `$cat Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN version=$(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.PHP_MINOR_VERSION;") \
&& curl -A "Docker" -o /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz -D - -L -s https://blackfire.io/api/v1/releases/probe/php/linux/amd64/$version \
&& mkdir -p /tmp/blackfire \
&& tar zxpf /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz -C /tmp/blackfire \
&& mv /tmp/blackfire/blackfire-*.so $(php -r "echo ini_get('extension_dir');")/blackfire.so \
&& printf "extension=blackfire.so\nblackfire.agent_socket=tcp://myapp:8707\n" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/blackfire.ini \
&& rm -rf /tmp/blackfire /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz


RUN apt-get update && \
#apt-get install -y php5-mysql && \
apt-get clean

COPY myapp /var/www/html/
```

**5. Build myapp container**
   `$docker build -t php-docker-apache-example` .

**6. Docker run**

```
$docker network create myphp

$docker run -d -p 8080:80 --net=myphp-app -v `pwd`:/var/www/html php-blackfire
```

**RESULT:**

```
Unable to find image 'php-blackfire:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for php-blackfire, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

`$ docker login`
Authenticating with existing credentials...
Login Succeeded

`$ docker run -d -p 8080:80 --net=myphp-app -v \`pwd`:/var/www/html php- 
blackfire`

```
Unable to find image 'php-blackfire:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for php-blackfire, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Then I tried to find Blackfire **local image**:

```
$docker images | grep black
blackfire/blackfire         latest              fe5c5468b23d        7 days ago          25.7MB
$ docker run -d -p 8080:80 --net=myphp -v pwd:/var/www/html blackfire/blackfire
26005945907dd55d55d174444dcf53ef176e5b45d0086309496122d0b02e3918
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7768e1266e81        blackfire/blackfire   "blackfire-agent"   38 minutes ago      Up 38 minutes       8707/tcp            blackfire
```

**7. Run the php application in container**

`$docker run -d -p 8080:80 php-docker-apache-example`

`$docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
6dd287bfbb44        php-docker-apache-example   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   determined_snyder
7768e1266e81        blackfire/blackfire         "blackfire-agent"        44 minutes ago       Up 44 minutes       8707/tcp               blackfire
```

**8. Browse http://localhost:8080/**

Displays: Hello. Today is Monday the 10th.

**9. Run the profiler in Chrome**

Error:

Are you authorized to profile this page? Probe not found, invalid signature (HTTP 200).  Troubleshooting?

docker logs does not show related errors:

```
$docker logs 6dd287bfbb44 -f
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Dec 10 22:24:13.490536 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/7.0.32 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 10 22:24:13.490688 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
172.17.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2018:22:25:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 407 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Could you solve this issue? I have the same error: "Are you authorized to profile this page?"